# Firestore Query in Android is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Database Snapshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YRBY.png)

Here is a piece of code I am using to get things from a collection into my own class object. I've now tried a bunch of things [using DocumentReference, looking up different code available online etc.] but the problem still persists.

I cannot retrieve data which I know is stored in the Firestore. When I execute the code, I get that the `QueryDocSnap is empty`.

```
CollectionReference reference = firestore.collection("data");
        reference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "QueryDocSnap is empty");
                } else {
                    List<ReportStore> types = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(ReportStore.class);

                    reportStores.addAll(types);
                    Global.setStoreData(reportStores);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error Getting Data", e);
            }
        });
```

`/app/store/data/4EOi3Eh1AkZf1rK5zwKt` is the hierarchy of my database with Firestore telling me that 'app' and 'data' are `Collection` and the other two are `Document`.

Could someone please clear out this confusion of mine. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your database structure.

Comment: @Ashish added the picture above.

Comment: The way your trying to retrieving won't work cause there is main collection app then store then data

Comment: @Ashish So, what should I do?

Comment: Let me build the query for you

Comment: @Ashish That would be great, thanks!

Comment: Check and tell me if it's working or not.

Comment: The problem with your code is you didn't provide proper path to your collection data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will provide you proper list of documents from `data`.

```
CollectionReference reference = firestore.collection("app").document("store").collection("data");
reference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked! I now have every thing stored inside the data document. Thank You!!